# How do I set Generate Debug Symbols to no XCode 8?

Tags: xcode, gcc, flags

Where do I set the Generate Debug Symbols flag to "NO" in the Build Settings in XCode 8. I am having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Under *Code Generation* you should be able to find *GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS* or *Generate Debug Symbols* [1], which can be set to **NO**.

Note that this option is only visible when showing "All" build settings, not when showing only "Basic" ones.

[1]: based on whether you chose "Show Settings Names" or "Titles" in the *Editor* menu